# How to enable forced listing with ember serve

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, eslint, lint

I need to enable forced es-linting with `ember serve`. When ever `ember serve` is run server should hold till all the **es-lintings errors are fixed**. I can do it with custom npm script, but want to look for ember-cli alternatives before writing my own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ESLint via the [Ember CLI ESLint](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint) addon. And it will integrate with `ember test` (or testing via the browser interface). I don't know if it'll actually fail the build, but it will fail your tests if you setup the ESLint rules to be errors, not just warnings.

Comment: Yes, but the reason behind is to prevent devs from following bad coding standards. And I have implemented it through pre-commit hook as to made more sense than stopping/holding build.